# Error installing via npm install

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, npm, yeoman

I'm getting below error running `npm install` on Ubuntu 12.04:

Below is part of my `npm-debug.log` around where I'm getting errors:

```
2221 verbose lock tar:///home/vagrant/.npm/lodash/0.9.2/package.tgz /home/vagrant/.npm/4605d2c2-ant-npm-lodash-0-9-2-package-tgz.lock
2222 silly gunzTarPerm modes [ '755', '644' ]
2223 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry package.json
2224 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry lib/js-yaml/type/merge.js
2225 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry lib/js-yaml/type/timestamp.js
2226 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry README.md
2227 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry lodash.js
2228 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry lib/js-yaml/type/null.js
2229 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry lib/js-yaml/type/js/function.js
2230 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry lodash.min.js
2231 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry lib/js-yaml/type/js/regexp.js
2232 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry lib/js-yaml/type/js/undefined.js
2233 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry lodash.underscore.js
2234 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry lodash.underscore.min.js
2235 error Error: UNKNOWN, symlink '../grunt-open/bin/grunt-open'
2236 error If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
2236 error including the npm and node versions, at:
2236 error     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
2237 error System Linux 3.2.0-23-generic
2238 error command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
2239 error cwd /var/www
2240 error node -v v0.10.26
2241 error npm -v 1.4.3
2242 error path ../grunt-open/bin/grunt-open
2243 error code UNKNOWN
2244 error errno -1
2245 verbose exit [ -1, true ]
```

This is my `package.json`:

```
{
    "name": "www",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node server"
    },
    "engines": {
        "node": ">=0.8.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "3.4.0",
        "ejs": "*"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "grunt": "~0.4.1",
        "grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.4.1",
        "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.3.0",
        "grunt-contrib-coffee": "~0.7.0",
        "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.2.0",
        "grunt-contrib-compass": "~0.3.0",
        "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.6.0",
        "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "~0.6.0",
        "grunt-contrib-connect": "~0.3.0",
        "grunt-contrib-clean": "~0.4.1",
        "grunt-contrib-htmlmin": "~0.1.3",
        "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "~0.1.4",
        "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.4.0",
        "grunt-usemin": "~0.1.11",
        "grunt-rev": "~0.1.0",
        "grunt-karma": "~0.4.3",
        "grunt-open": "~0.2.0",
        "grunt-concurrent": "~0.3.0",
        "matchdep": "~0.1.2",
        "connect-livereload": "~0.2.0",
        "grunt-google-cdn": "~0.2.0",
        "grunt-ngmin": "~0.0.2",
        "grunt-express": "~1.2.1",
        "time-grunt": "~0.1.1"
    }
}
```

Basically I've used `Yeoman` to generate mean stack using `yo meanstack` then `npm install` on the same directory.

Is there something that I should fix here?

Answer (score 1):

As i can guess from the log you're running vagrant box. You should take a look at this issue:

https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/issues/1058

> ... VM software failing to account for the fact that sym-links don't exist in Windows. If you're running Vagrant, upgrade to the latest version.